# Checkboxes when un checked and saved then uncheck is not saved in form in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

i have two checkboxes in my form(ruby on rails application) like below.

When i check these checkboxes and save then the checkboxes are getting checked and saved(till this its working fine).

after that when we uncheck and save these checkboxes, then these uncheck changes are not getting saved.(still showing checked.)

these are working in my local rails development environment. but the same code is not working in the server.

below is my code

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => url_for(:controller => 'user_controller', :action => 'investor_create_or_update'),html: { class: 'migrate-form' }, remote: true do |f| %>

<%= f.check_box :are_you_a_owner, class: "", placeholder: ""%><label>Are you a Business owner or Senior Manager?

<% end %>
```

Comment: what are the values you are expecting from it to be saved in your DB?

Answer (score 0):

What are the values you are expecting from it to be saved in your DB? If for instance `1` and `0` then

```
  <%= f.check_box :are_you_a_owner,{ class: "", placeholder: ""}, "1", "0" %>
```

should do the trick I guess. Here `1` is for checked and `0` for unchecked.